Why negation blocks match
Trying to extract 21954901 from text
20309  NARVA
Arve number:_21954901
Arve number. Täname.
Kliendi number:_11654

using this pattern
(?si)(.*?[_\s]Arve number[\s_:.]*(^TÄNAME))(?<arvenumber>[^\s_]+).*?

It returns no match. Why is the match not found?
How to find match 21954901 into arvenumber group?
Testcase: https://regex101.com/r/B2jOVx/1
I'm using C# on .NET 8

The value 21954901 comes before Täname right? It depends how strict the requirements are, but this would capture it (?im)^Arve number:[ _:.]+(?<arvenumber>\d+)\r?\n.*\sTäname\. https://regex101.com/r/lnNg0j/1 or https://regex101.com/r/CTWMak/1

Instead of "why doesn't it work", you need to specify when it should work. Why is your regex that complex? What specs did you try to implement?

(^TÄNAME) isn’t a negation. regex101 will even explain that for you if you hover over it.

This regex pattern will give you the number in the arvenumber group. The main change is the Either pattern to select between ‘Täname’ or the number.
(?si).*?Arve number[\s_:.]*(TÄNAME|(?<arvenumber>[^\s_]+))

If the arvenumber always consists of digits, this is an alternative:
(?si).*?Arve number[\s_:.]*(?<arvenumber>[0-9]+)

